# Jekyll conversion not working on updating the Ruby version

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll

I have updated my **Ruby** from **ruby 2.5.1p57** (*2018-03-29 revision 63029*) [x64-mingw32] to **ruby 2.7.4p191** (*2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23*) [x64-mingw32]. While trying to convert a `.md` file into `.html` file using `jekyll serve`, I got error like:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Markdown encountered an error while converting 'blazor/Release-Notes/v19.1.54.md':
                    No such file or directory - py
Traceback (most recent call last):
        29: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        28: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        27: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        26: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
        25: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
        24: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:80:in `process'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:211:in `render'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:538:in `render_pages'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:538:in `each'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:539:in `block in render_pages'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:547:in `render_regenerated'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:63:in `run'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:84:in `render_document'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:104:in `convert'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:104:in `reduce'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:104:in `each'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:106:in `block in convert'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown.rb:85:in `convert'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:109:in `getset'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:88:in `[]': unhandled exception
        48: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        47: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        46: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        45: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
        44: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
        43: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
        42: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
        41: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
        40: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        39: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        38: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
        37: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        36: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
        35: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
        34: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        33: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:80:in `process'
        32: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:211:in `render'
        31: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:538:in `render_pages'
        30: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:538:in `each'
        29: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:539:in `block in render_pages'
        28: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:547:in `render_regenerated'
        27: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:63:in `run'
        26: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:84:in `render_document'
        25: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:104:in `convert'
        24: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:104:in `reduce'
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:104:in `each'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:106:in `block in convert'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown.rb:85:in `convert'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:108:in `getset'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:111:in `rescue in getset'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown.rb:86:in `block in convert'
        17: from D:/documentationautomation/website/_plugins/kramdown_pygments.rb:105:in `convert'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.1/lib/kramdown/document.rb:116:in `method_missing'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.1/lib/kramdown/converter/base.rb:107:in `convert'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.1/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb:58:in `convert'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.1/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb:373:in `convert_root'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.1/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb:70:in `inner'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.1/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb:70:in `each'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.1/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb:71:in `block in inner'
         9: from D:/documentationautomation/website/_plugins/kramdown_pygments.rb:49:in `convert_codeblock'
         8: from D:/documentationautomation/website/_plugins/kramdown_pygments.rb:73:in `pygmentize'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:235:in `highlight'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pygments.rb-2.2.0/lib/pygments/popen.rb:175:in `highlight'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pygments.rb-2.2.0/lib/pygments/popen.rb:253:in `mentos'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pygments.rb-2.2.0/lib/pygments/popen.rb:32:in `start'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pygments.rb-2.2.0/lib/pygments/popen.rb:184:in `popen4'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:101:in `popen3'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:213:in `popen_run'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:213:in `spawn': No such file or directory - py (Errno::ENOENT)



                    No such file or directory - py
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.2.0   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command
                     for any additional information or backtrace.
                    ------------------------------------------------
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try appending `--trace` to the `serve` command for additional information or a backtrace?

Comment: Please find the trace back details added in question part itself now

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after you switched Ruby versions?